# SSMS Disk usage reports reports no data file for online database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

We have a rather large database running on SQL Server 2012. The data file is now 2 118 256 MB. For a couple of weeks now, whenever I run the SSMS report Disk Usage, it says at the very bottom that "There is no data file for MyDatabase database."

Anyone seen this before? The database is up and running. Is there a size constraint on what this report will show?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, this report fails when the database is over 2 TB.

See this connect item: [SQL Server Management Studio Standard Reports - Disk Usage](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/596145/sql-server-management-studio-standard-reports-disk-usage)

> Create a new 2 TB database and run the Disk Usage report to display
> results.
>
> ---
>
> For Disk Space Used by Data Files, rather than displaying the Filegroup Name, Logical File Name, Physical File Name, Space Reserved,
> Space Used, I get a message of "There is no data file for 
> database."